# What does the `priority` parameter do to GCM Messages?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Google recently introduced the parameter `priority` in their [documentation of GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref#table1). The documentation reads:

> Sets the priority of the message. Use values between 0 - 10, where the higher value represents higher priority.

But what does this priority actually mean? What do the different values, 0 - 10, indicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of time I found the answer: `priority` is an argument used in notifications for iOS (like [the newly added `content_available` parameter](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref#table1)).

The documentation for `priority` is well hidden, but can be find in [The Binary Interface and Notification Format](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW9), in the table of "items and their identifiers":

> The notification’s priority. Provide one of the following values:
>
> - `10` The push message is sent immediately.
>     The remote notification must trigger an alert, sound, or badge on the device. It is an error to use this priority for a push that contains only the content-available key.
> - `5` The push message is sent at a time that conserves power on the device receiving it.